# How can I use induction for proving termination of a string rewriting system?

Tags: proof-techniques, induction, term-rewriting, termination

If we have a string rewriting system within the alphabet $\{X,Y\}^*$ and the rule $XY\to YX$. How can we prove by induction that on every string input the system terminates?

Answer (score 1):

It's your exercise, so I'll let you answer it, but here is a hint.  Consider the sequence of words visited by repeatedly applying the rewrite rule and its relationship to [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).  Work through a few examples and see if you can form a conjecture.